# Nokogiri XML to hash using attibute names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, attributes, nokogiri

I'm new to rails and I'm looking to parse an XML from Pubmed Eutil's API into a hash with the attributes I want.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def pubmed_search
new
if params[:search_terms].present?
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  @search_terms = params[:search_terms].split.join("+")
  uid_url = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term="+@search_terms    
  uid_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(uid_url)) 
  @uid = uid_doc.xpath("//id").map {|uid| uid.text}.join(",")
  detail_url = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id="+@uid
  detail_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(detail_url))
  @details = @detail_doc.xpath("//item[@name='Title']|//item[@name='FullJournalName']|//item[@name='Author']").map{|article| 
    article.text}
  render :new
else    
  render :new
end
```

This gives me the values I want (Authors, Title, Journal Name) but it comes out in one giant array without the attribute names like so:

```
["Keshmiri-Neghab H", "Goliaei B", "Nikoofar A", "Gossypol enhances radiation induced autophagy in glioblastoma multiforme.", "General physiology and biophysics", "Alzahrani EO", "Asiri A", "El-Dessoky MM", "Kuang Y", "Quiescence as an explanation of Gompertzian tumor growth revisited.", "Mathematical biosciences", "Neofytou M", "Tanos V", "Constantinou I", "Kyriacou E", "Pattichis M", "Pattichis C", "Computer Aided Diagnosis in Hysteroscopic Imaging.", "IEEE journal of biomedical and health informatics", "Lou Q", "Ji L", "Zhong W", "Li S", "Yu S", "Li Z", "Meng X", "Synthesis and Cytotoxicity Evaluation of Naphthalimide Derived N-Mustards.", "Molecules (Basel, Switzerland)", "Sesang W", "Punyanitya S", "Pitchuanchom S", "Udomputtimekakul P", "Nuntasaen N", "Banjerdpongchai R", "Wudtiwai B", "Pompimon W", "Cytotoxic Aporphine Alkaloids from Leaves and Twigs of Pseuduvaria trimera (Craib).", "Molecules (Basel, Switzerland)", "Yang XK", "Xu MY", "Xu GS", "Zhang YL", "Xu ZX", "In Vitro and in Vivo Antitumor Activity of Scutebarbatine A on Human Lung Carcinoma A549 Cell Lines.", "Molecules (Basel, Switzerland)", "Yang CY", "Lu RH", "Lin CH", "Jen CH", "Tung CY", "Yang SH", "Lin JK", "Jiang JK", "Lin CH", "Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms Associated with Colorectal Cancer Susceptibility and Loss of Heterozygosity in a Taiwanese Population.", "PloS one", "Zhang H", "Gu L", "Liu T", "Chiang KY", "Zhou M", "Inhibition of MDM2 by Nilotinib Contributes to Cytotoxicity in Both Philadelphia-Positive and Negative Acute Lymphoblastic Leukemia.", "PloS one", "Oliveira A", "Pinho D", "Albino-Teixeira A", "Medeiros R", "Dinis-Oliveira RJ", "Carvalho F", "Morphine glucuronidation increases its analgesic effect in guinea-pigs.", "Life sciences", "Kabbout M", "Dakhlallah D", "Sharma S", "Bronisz A", "Srinivasan R", "Piper M", "Marsh CB", "Ostrowski MC", "MicroRNA 17-92 Cluster Mediates ETS1 and ETS2-Dependent RAS-Oncogenic Transformation.", "PloS one", "Kannen H", "Hazama H", "Kaneda Y", "Fujino T", "Awazu K", "Development of Laser Ionization Techniques for Evaluation of the Effect of Cancer Drugs Using Imaging Mass Spectrometry.", "International journal of molecular sciences", "Liang J", "Tong P", "Zhao W", "Li Y", "Zhang L", "Xia Y", "Yu Y", "The REST Gene Signature Predicts Drug Sensitivity in Neuroblastoma Cell Lines and Is Significantly Associated with Neuroblastoma Tumor Stage.", "International journal of molecular sciences", "Mathur A", "Ware C", "Davis L", "Gazdar A", "Pan BS", "Lutterbach B", "FGFR2 Is Amplified in the NCI-H716 Colorectal Cancer Cell Line and Is Required for Growth and Survival.", "PloS one", "van As JW", "van den Berg H", "van Dalen EC", "Different infusion durations for preventing platinum-induced hearing loss in children with cancer.", "The Cochrane database of systematic reviews", "Lynam-Lennon N", "Maher SG", "Maguire A", "Phelan J", "Muldoon C", "Reynolds JV", "O'Sullivan J", "Altered Mitochondrial Function and Energy Metabolism Is Associated with a Radioresistant Phenotype in Oesophageal Adenocarcinoma.", "PloS one", "Meriggi F", "Andreis F", "Premi V", "Liborio N", "Codignola C", "Mazzocchi M", "Rizzi A", "Prochilo T", "Rota L", "Di Biasi B", "Bertocchi P", "Abeni C", "Ogliosi C", "Aroldi F", "Zaniboni A", "Assessing cancer caregivers' needs for an early targeted psychosocial support project: The experience of the oncology department of the Poliambulanza Foundation.", "Palliative & supportive care", "Gwede CK", "Davis SN", "Wilson S", "Patel M", "Vadaparampil ST", "Meade CD", "Rivers BM", "Yu D", "Torres-Roca J", "Heysek R", "Spiess PE", "Pow-Sang J", "Jacobsen P", "Perceptions of Prostate Cancer Screening Controversy and Informed Decision Making: Implications for Development of a Targeted Decision Aid for Unaffected Male First-Degree Relatives.", "American journal of health promotion : AJHP", "Simerska P", "Suksamran T", "Ziora ZM", "Rivera FD", "Engwerda C", "Toth I", "Ovalbumin lipid core peptide vaccines and their CD4<sup>+</sup> and CD8<sup>+</sup> T cell responses.", "Vaccine", "Ogembo JG", "Manga S", "Nulah K", "Foglabenchi LH", "Perlman S", "Wamai RG", "Welty T", "Welty E", "Tih P", "Achieving high uptake of human papillomavirus vaccine in Cameroon: Lessons learned in overcoming challenges.", "Vaccine", "Chung CY", "Alden SL", "Funderburg NT", "Fu P", "Levine AD", "Progressive Proximal-to-Distal Reduction in Expression of the Tight Junction Complex in Colonic Epithelium of Virally-Suppressed HIV+ Individuals.", "PLoS pathogens"]
```

What I'm looking for instead would be:

```
@details = {{:Title => {"title1"}, :Authors => {"author1", "author2", "author3"}, :Journal => {"journal1"}},{:Title => {"title2"}, :Authors => {"author4", "author5", "author6"}, :Journal => {"journal2"}}
```

I've tried some .to_hash methods described in other answers, but they don't create a hash that deals with the XML attributes very well, as the name of the attributes I want are in the @name attribute for each "item".  Here is some sample XML from pubmed:

```
<eSummaryResult><DocSum><Id>11850928</Id><Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">1965 Aug</Item><Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date"/><Item Name="Source" Type="String">Arch Dermatol</Item><Item Name="AuthorList" Type="List"><Item Name="Author" Type="String">LoPresti PJ</Item><Item Name="Author" Type="String">Hambrick GW Jr</Item></Item><Item Name="LastAuthor" Type="String">Hambrick GW Jr</Item><Item Name="Title" Type="String">Zirconium granuloma following treatment of rhus dermatitis.</Item><Item Name="Volume" Type="String">92</Item><Item Name="Issue" Type="String">2</Item><Item Name="Pages" Type="String">188-91</Item><Item Name="LangList" Type="List"><Item Name="Lang" Type="String">English</Item></Item><Item Name="NlmUniqueID" Type="String">0372433</Item><Item Name="ISSN" Type="String">0003-987X</Item><Item Name="ESSN" Type="String">1538-3652</Item><Item Name="PubTypeList" Type="List"><Item Name="PubType" Type="String">Journal Article</Item></Item><Item Name="RecordStatus" Type="String">PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE</Item><Item Name="PubStatus" Type="String">ppublish</Item><Item Name="ArticleIds" Type="List"><Item Name="pubmed" Type="String">11850928</Item><Item Name="eid" Type="String">11850928</Item><Item Name="rid" Type="String">11850928</Item></Item><Item Name="History" Type="List"><Item Name="pubmed" Type="Date">1965/08/01 00:00</Item><Item Name="medline" Type="Date">2002/03/09 10:01</Item><Item Name="entrez" Type="Date">1965/08/01 00:00</Item></Item><Item Name="References" Type="List"/><Item Name="HasAbstract" Type="Integer">1</Item><Item Name="PmcRefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item><Item Name="FullJournalName" Type="String">Archives of dermatology</Item><Item Name="ELocationID" Type="String"/><Item Name="SO" Type="String">1965 Aug;92(2):188-91</Item></DocSum><DocSum><Id>11482001</Id><Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">2001 Jun</Item><Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date"/><Item Name="Source" Type="String">Adverse Drug React Toxicol Rev</Item><Item Name="AuthorList" Type="List"><Item Name="Author" Type="String">Mantle D</Item><Item Name="Author" Type="String">Gok MA</Item><Item Name="Author" Type="String">Lennard TW</Item></Item><Item Name="LastAuthor" Type="String">Lennard TW</Item><Item Name="Title" Type="String">Adverse and beneficial effects of plant extracts on skin and skin disorders.</Item><Item Name="Volume" Type="String">20</Item><Item Name="Issue" Type="String">2</Item><Item Name="Pages" Type="String">89-103</Item><Item Name="LangList" Type="List"><Item Name="Lang" Type="String">English</Item></Item><Item Name="NlmUniqueID" Type="String">9109474</Item><Item Name="ISSN" Type="String">0964-198X</Item><Item Name="ESSN" Type="String"/><Item Name="PubTypeList" Type="List"><Item Name="PubType" Type="String">Journal Article</Item><Item Name="PubType" Type="String">Review</Item></Item><Item Name="RecordStatus" Type="String">PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE</Item><Item Name="PubStatus" Type="String">ppublish</Item><Item Name="ArticleIds" Type="List"><Item Name="pubmed" Type="String">11482001</Item><Item Name="eid" Type="String">11482001</Item><Item Name="rid" Type="String">11482001</Item></Item><Item Name="History" Type="List"><Item Name="pubmed" Type="Date">2001/08/03 10:00</Item><Item Name="medline" Type="Date">2002/01/23 10:01</Item><Item Name="entrez" Type="Date">2001/08/03 10:00</Item></Item><Item Name="References" Type="List"/><Item Name="HasAbstract" Type="Integer">1</Item><Item Name="PmcRefCount" Type="Integer">3</Item><Item Name="FullJournalName" Type="String">Adverse drug reactions and toxicological reviews</Item><Item Name="ELocationID" Type="String"/><Item Name="SO" Type="String">2001 Jun;20(2):89-103</Item></DocSum></eSummaryResult>
```

Thanks for any help, I've been dying trying to finding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this, the structure of the xml does not match the structure of your required hash. You must pick out the desired nodes from the xml manually and construct the hash from their values. Using xpath is probably the easiest, the code might look something like this:

```
@details = []
detail_doc.xpath("/eSummaryResult/DocSum").each do |node|
  detail = {}
  detail[:title] = node.xpath("Item[@Name='Title']").text
  detail[:journal] = node.xpath("Item[@Name='Journal']").text
  detail[:authors] = node.xpath("Item[@Name='AuthorList']/Item[@Name='Author']").map{|n| n.text}
  @details.push(detail)
end
```